# Can a dojo TabContainer be configured to switch by mouse over?

Tags: dojo

I'm using dojo toolkit dijit.layout.TabContainer to switch 3 tabbed pages.
Right now I click on tabs to switch them, but I want to switch them by mouse over instead.

Can a TabContainer be configured to switch by mouse over, or should I write a code to handle mouse over events to explicitly switch tabs?

I'd appreciate any suggestions!

-Sari

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For this functionality, we need to add the onmouseover event to the tabs label fields. Add this code inside the dojo/ready (or addOnLoad) function.

```
require(["dojo/ready","dojo/query"], function(ready,query){
  ready(function(){
    var tabs = dijit.byId("TabContainerID");
    query("#TabContainerID.dijitTabInner").onmouseover(function(evt){
     var tablabelid = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(evt.target).id;
     var currentId = dijit.byId("TabContainerID").selectedChildWidget;
     var tabwidid = tablabelid.split("_").pop();
     if(tabwidid && currentId!=tabwidid) {
      tabs.selectChild(tabwidid);
     }
   });
  });
});
```